# What does this plot represent for 3 phase induction motor?

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc-motor, induction-motor, efficiency

I got a 3 phase induction motor with the following plot (please see below).

[image]

On Y axis: Pm + Pfe represent the mechanical and iron losses, Pm being the mechanical losses, and PFe the iron losses.

On X axis: That's the electrical nominal tension U. In this case U10n = U1n.

The 3 phase induction motor is being charged at tensions between 80% U1n and U1n where U10 is the charging tension.

Can someone please explain why the plot behaves like that? Like what would be the mechanism behind that behaviour?

Many thanks!

Comment: It looks normal to me so, what are you seeing in the diagram that seems so unnatural to you?

Comment: @Andyaka nothing unnatural, just wanted to get the grasp of the mechanism that produces that behaviour.

Comment: Like what would be the phenomena behind it?

Comment: Magnetic saturation losses.

Comment: As it's an induction motor the mechanical loss is almost independent of V but the magnetisation (iron) losses are not. This graph suggests they are proportional to V^2 within that range : does the text explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanical losses are bearing friction and aerodynamic drag. Those losses are not influenced by voltage. Power lost to bearing friction is directly proportional to speed because the torque loss is not much influenced by speed, but power is torque multiplied by speed. Power lost to aerodynamic drag is proportional to the cube of speed because is is like the power to drive a fan. Some of the drag loss is literally due to driving an internal or external fan that cools the motor.

The fact that mechanical losses are constant tells you that the change in voltage as no effect on speed. Not much speed change would be expected if the voltage changes without changing the frequency. However changing the voltage does change the available torque capability. For that reason, it is likely that the plot represents on-load motor operation.

Iron loss in an induction motor is proportional to voltage. Increasing the voltage increases the motor's magnetizing current and the iron losses. That loss is represented in the equivalent circuit by a resistor that is nearly directly across the power line terminals. Only the small stator winding resistance and inductance is in series.